# Can I use parameter to define field name

Tags: javascript, jquery, flot

The following JavaScript code works, but is there a more compact way to write it using **n** parameter, to "eval" y**1**axis, y**2**axis, y**3**axis field names?

```
  switch (n) {
    case 1:
      markingsY = [
             { color: colorErr, y1axis: { from: maxVal } },
             { color: colorErr, y1axis: { to: minVal } },
             { color: "#00f", lineWidth: 1, y1axis: { from: minVal, to: minVal } },
             { color: "#00f", lineWidth: 1, y1axis: { from: maxVal, to: maxVal } }
          ];
    break;

    case 2:
      markingsY = [
             { color: colorErr, y2axis: { from: maxVal } },
             { color: colorErr, y2axis: { to: minVal } },
             { color: "#00f", lineWidth: 1, y2axis: { from: minVal, to: minVal } },
             { color: "#00f", lineWidth: 1, y2axis: { from: maxVal, to: maxVal } }
          ];
    break;

    case 3:
      markingsY = [
             { color: colorErr, y3axis: { from: maxVal } },
             { color: colorErr, y3axis: { to: minVal } },
             { color: "#00f", lineWidth: 1, y3axis: { from: minVal, to: minVal } },
             { color: "#00f", lineWidth: 1, y3axis: { from: maxVal, to: maxVal } }
          ];
    break;

    default:
    break;


  }
```

Comment: What is the expected input and output?

Comment: input: n - integer, output markingsY, array, with fieldnames that relates to n, y1axis, y2axis, y3axis

Comment: For some things, flot uses `yaxis` instead of `y1axis`, maybe both can work. And btw: I already did what you ask here in the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35912739/2610249) to your earlier question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Misread the question, Sorry!

You could use a static key instead of the one you need to change, then change it dynamically, so:

```
markingsY = [
    { color: colorErr, yaxis: { from: maxVal } },
    { color: colorErr, yaxis: { to: minVal } },
    { color: "#00f", lineWidth: 1, yaxis: { from: minVal, to: minVal } },
    { color: "#00f", lineWidth: 1, yaxis: { from: maxVal, to: maxVal } }
];
markingsY.forEach(function(item){
    item["y"+n+"axis"]=item.yaxis;//copy it to its new key
    delete item.yaxis;//remove the old one
});
```

Comment: can i use it as -

var lookup = {
  1:[y1axis],
  2:[y2axis],
  3:[y3axis],
};

markingsY = [
  { color: colorErr, lookup[n]: { from: maxVal } },
  { color: colorErr, lookup[n]: { to: minVal } },
  { color: "#00f", lineWidth: 1, lookup[n]: { from: minVal, to: minVal } },
  { color: "#00f", lineWidth: 1, lookup[n]: { from: maxVal, to: maxVal } }
];

Comment: I seem to have misread you question, Sorry, I have edited my answer to more of what you want, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var n = 10

    var collections = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        var json1 = {}
      var row = [];
      json1['color'] = '#000000';
      json1['y'+i+'axis'] = {from: 1234};
      row.push(json1);
      collections.push(row);
    }

    console.log(collections);
```

You will have the collection of 10 markingsY arrays.
each markingsY  array has (my code) 1 JSON

```
collections = [ 
    [{color:#0000000, y0axis:{form:1234}}], 
    [{color:#0000000, y1axis:{form:1234}}] 
.....];
```

Then your switch(n) can be replaced:

```
collections[n]
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kingychiu/ow1e3h4x/